# Looping JSON structure using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

**JSON**

```
{
    "form": {
        "roles": {
          "role": [
            { "name": "RoleB" },
            { "name": "RoleA" }
          ]
        },
        "rows":[
            {
                "id":"1",                               
                "fields":{              
                    "field":[
                        {
                            "fname":"Matt"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I access the value of `fname` using jquery?

**This is what I'm doing** --

```
jQuery.each(response.form.rows.fields.field, function(i, val){
     alert(this.fname);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch out for those arrays....

`response.form.rows[0].fields.field[0].fname`

Or, in your case (and assuming there's only one `rows` element):

```
jQuery.each(response.form.rows[0].fields.field, function(i, val){
     alert(this.fname);
});
```

If there's more than one element in `rows`, you need a second loop:

```
jQuery.each(response.form.rows, function() {
    jQuery.each(this.fields.field, function(i, val) {
        alert(val.fname);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/33H8L/